# Autocomplete-rails gem suggestion when enter first key with rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

Is there any way to get suggestion of list when enter first key, Currently, It is providing suggestion list when enter more than one key in search box.

I am using `gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'`

And autocomplete text look like:

`<%=autocomplete_field_tag 'hotel_name', '', autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name_hotels_path,:placeholder=>"Search...", :class=>"search", :onfocus=>"this.placeholder = ''", :onblur=> "this.placeholder = 'Search...'", :data => { :no_matches_label => "" } %>`

Comment: it should not behave like this ...........anyway did you use any `keyevents` on you autocomplete field?

Comment: It looking like this `<%=autocomplete_field_tag 'hotel_name', '', autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name_hotels_path,:placeholder=>"Search...", :class=>"search", :onfocus=>"this.placeholder = ''", :onblur=> "this.placeholder = 'Search...'", :data => { :no_matches_label => "" } %>`

Comment: what is this `:data => { :no_matches_label => "" }`

Comment: I am trying to remove "no data matches" suggestion. but it is also not working

Comment: When I used an old version of `jqueryui`, `autocomplete` seemed that it needed two characters to trigger, you can use javascript set the "minLength" option to 1 or 0 and try it again.

Comment: can you simple write `<%=autocomplete_field_tag 'hotel_name', '', autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name_hotels_path, :class=>"search" %>`

Comment: @RajarshiDas, I tried but it is being behave same

Comment: @Bigxiang, I have applied minlength 0 then tried but it is not working. also tried with 1

Comment: what is you rails version is it 3? and jquery-ui version?

Comment: rails 3.2 and jquery "1.9.1"